# Text-based geometry program to draw competition level geometry pictures

Tags: open-source

What software one should recommend for drawing euclidean geometry figures? I mean, I would like to learn to make pictures like this:

[example http://www.math-olympiad.com/image/imo/diag674.jpg](http://www.math-olympiad.com/image/imo/diag674.jpg)

I like more about writing code than using mouse. Is TikZ + LaTeX the best combination?

Comment: A long time ago I used AutoCAD for such things, but its too long ago that I could still recommend it in good faith. You might want to have a look at it though.

Comment: Yes, I think that TikZ is a very good tool for such figures. It can take time to learn, but it'll be rewarding

Comment: Two ideas: 1) Geogebra lets you export graphics to LaTeX/PSTricks. I don't know about the code's quality though. 2) Tikzedit is a Tikz editor which lets you combine GUI and text based editing.